# android: how to refresh a tab after button click

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have page with a button and tabs below. I want the tab which is opened to reflect the change in variable data after i click the button. I am not able to understand it.

The following is my **code**:-

```
public class Level2MainActivity_grid1 extends AppCompatActivity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.level2mainlayout_place1);



        // I am putting a viewpager with fragments into them and put tabs

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);



        Button buttonId = (Button) findViewById(R.id.planmytraveludupitown);
        buttonId.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            //I want to save some things and also refresh the current tab

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to display api data on button click??

Answer (score 1):

Below line also works but incase it don't work then you can try another option also

```
  pagerAdapter.notifydatasetChanged();
```

Try below code :-

```
     buttonId.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


 pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

            }
        });
```

**Note**:- when you get new data redefine your Titles and Numoftabs again

Comment: it works. But the tab changes to first one. how to see the tab does not change

Comment: This works because you create a whole new pager adapter, and thats why it changes to the first tab.

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi then try first option as well

Comment: I tried the first option but the data is not changing. in the second one its changing

Comment: You can save which tab was being displayed by getCurrentItem of view pager and when a new adapter is created you can pass setCurrentItem to that. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you notify the dataset in your adapter ?

`pagerAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`

Comment: Try to do that inside the `onClick` method. Just call `pagerAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();`

Comment: I tried this it did not change the data immediately. When i go to other tab and come back to this tab the changes are shown

Comment: By the way i am using fragmentpageradapter

Comment: Try to call after `pagerAdapter.notifyDatasetChange();` the following :
`viewPager.destroyDrawingCache();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97289/discussion-between-santhosh-yedidi-and-flm).